# Difference between mailbox statistics for Get-EXOMailboxStatistics and Graph API getMailboxUsageDetail

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the mailbox item count & total size for every mailbox in our organization. I've tried using Get-EXOMailboxStatistics and Graph API and the figures are close but different.

For Graph API then I'm using "Item Count" & "Storage Used (Byte)". For Get-EXOMailboxStatistics then I'm using & "ItemCount" & "TotalItemSize"

Graph API: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getMailboxUsageDetail(period='D7')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getMailboxUsageDetail(period=%27D7%27))

What explains the difference between them? Does one of them include tasks, contacts, calendar etc? The documentation isn't clear. I've looked at various users and it's not always the same function that is higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Get-EXOMailboxStatistics this is live data, where as the getMailboxUsageDetail is a scheduled based report stored in a Data-mart (this is why it can be returned so fast). It's not documented in the Graph docs anywhere but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/activity-reports?view=o365-worldwide

> Reports are available for the last 7 days, 30 days, 90 days, and 180 days. Data won't exist for all reporting periods right away. The reports typically become available within 48 hours, but might sometimes take several days to become available.

uses the same data source.

Comment: Thank you. Do both methods consider exactly the same mailbox items? (i.e. Email, tasks, contacts & calandar). getMailboxUsageDetails just returns user mailboxes. And is there a way to get the same data for other mailbox types from Graph API? I know that I can call Get-EXOMailboxStatistics and filter by recipient type if necessary but I'd rather use Graph API for all of the data.

Comment: Its not documented but my guess is that they use the same underlying raw API to get the Mailbox size. Get-EXOMailboxStatistics is a lot more detailed as you can get retained items, archives and you can see the underlying table sizes etc (a lot of this is interesting information but not relevant to end users). What you see is what you get with getMailboxUsageDetails  it doesn't allow the same flexibility in terms of filtering and you can still only output a CSV in the v1.0 endpoint (where you can get a json result in the beta)